# Put sku data from a exisitng csv to a new csv file

Tags: php, csv

I want to put only the data[0] from a csv to a new csv file . 
The data 0 of the file 138702_fr contains some skus. I want to put in new.csv the sku which starts with M or O.

I don't know how i can do it .

```
// Open the output csv file
$outputfp = fopen('new.csv', 'w');

// Read from the input csv file
if (($inputfp = fopen("138702_fr.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

    while (($data = fgetcsv($inputfp, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {

        $line=array();

        $line[]=$data[0];

        // Write the line to the file
        fputcsv($outputfp, $line);
    }

    // Clean up
    fclose($inputfp);
    fclose($outputfp);
}
```

I tried to add this function :

```
<?php
$outputfp = fopen('new.csv', 'w');

if (($inputfp = fopen("138702_fr.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

    while (($data = fgetcsv($inputfp, 1000, "|")) !== FALSE) {

        $line=array();

        // SKU
        $line[]=$data[1];
        $price_calcul=(($data[4]*0.20)+$data[4])+2.5;
        $line[] = number_format($price_calcul,2); 
        $line[]=$data[9];

        if(in_array(strtoupper($line[1]), array('E','O')))
        fputcsv($outputfp, $line);

    }

    // Clean up
    fclose($inputfp);
    fclose($outputfp);
}
?>
```

Comment: Do not ask a new question, instead edit the previous one to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = fopen("input.csv","r");
$output = fopen("output.csv","w");

// while there are rows in the input csv
while($row = fgetcsv($input)) {
    // check if sku ($row[0]) starts with M, m, O or o
    if(in_array(strtoupper($row[0][0]), array('M','O')))
        // if it does, write it to the output file
        fputcsv($output, array($row[0]));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried to add this condiiton in my code but it doesn't work . Look i've edited my post . Thanks

Comment: The SKU is $data[1] in my case, sorry not the data 0 . I'm waiting your answer ;) thanks